# DFP won't end line item

Tags: google-dfp

Trying to end a line item in DoubleClick for Publishers. Line item is currently paused, all creatives deactivated. I want end the line, but it's telling me that my end date is earlier than the start date.
[as you can see, November 24 is not later than February 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2EOj.jpg)

Why is it doing this, and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the case if the end date(time) is before the current day. Try set the same day and hour ahead of current time..

Also you can pause the line item